# How do I mark a homebrew tap cask formulae as updated?

Tags: homebrew, homebrew-cask

I have a homebrew cask that downloads and installs a pre-built pkg.

```rb
cask "mypkg" do
  version "1.0.0.0"
  sha256 "4b928d..."

  url "https://location/my.pkg",

  name "mytestpkg"
  desc "My Test Pkg"

  pkg "#{version}-My-Test-Package.pkg"

  uninstall pkgutil: "my.pkg"

end
```

Recently I applied a bump and updated the version and sha. I tried running `brew upgrade` but no update / change was detected.

but the only way to get the update was to

- uninstall the cask
- uninstall the tap
- install the tap
- install the cask

Is there a way that a cask or tap can be marked as upgraded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `brew update` before `brew upgrade` then homebrew will detect the formulae has changed in the repo.

Comment: I'd forgotten about `brew update` thanks for the pointer.